# Appdelegate foreground/ background / active/ inactive processes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, process, appdelegate

i am working on an ios application, this app allows its user to add tasks that he have to do later on. after finishing adding this task it will be sent to the server to save on server side. now i am confused from some cases: what is my user have a call while entering task details..? or when he choose to save task and while this he receive a call ! what if the internet is off before doing so !! after having the call i must back to the last state in the application and data must not be lost, moreover ios must not kill the process, how can i do this using appdelegate methods ?

any help please ? and thanks in progress ..

Answer (score 4):

Apple provides delegate methods to manage life cycle of the application there are methods present in the App Delegate which you can use to achieve your functinality i am still briefing you the methods and its usage below which may be helpful to you.

Prior to ios4 we have the methods as follows:
1.**applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions**
2.**applicaitonDidbecomeActive**
3.**applicationwillTerminate**

From and after ios4 came the new method including the above.
1.**applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions**
2.**applicaitonDidbecomeActive**
3.**applicationWillResignActive**
4.**applicationDidEnterBackground**
5.**applicationWillEnterForeground**
6.**applicationwillTerminate**

In case of interrupt handling please find the complete flow in the Image attached it will be a lot clear to you.

[image: iOS Interrupt handling]

Comment: ok, i notice that when i am presenting  my uiViewController and i click home button, then go back to the application.. data are not deleted and it is there,, so why do i need to use these methods ?

Comment: Are you trying delete data from your presented view controller ? If you can explain a bit more may be i can help.

Comment: no, in android, the system kill the process (app) in sum conditions like (pressing back button) so you have to take care about this and save your data before that in order not to loss it, in ios is it the same? when having a phone call or sms? when i answer the call and finish it dose my view controller become visible and having its data?

Comment: i just want to ensure that user data will not be lost, if the user have a call, sms, notification or whatever

Comment: You can use app delegate method if the Phone rings applicationWillResignActive and save your manage context if you are using core data to save your data in the application.This will hold the data of the current state which you are working on.Please let me know if you need more help

Comment: i am using core data, but i am doing the process of saving that data when the user select "save", why should i save data before choosing save!! what if the user changes his mind about that task and he cancel it